# How can I change the default color theme in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the default color theme in VSCode to "Solarized Light", but I am unable to do so. The moment I save my "settings.json" file, the editor automatically changes whatever selection I've made back to "Default Dark+". This is odd because Default Dark+ is not an installed color theme, which is why you can see the red underline beneath the selection in the editor.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ME1yJ0I6kEA

I have tried changing this setting in both the UI and settings.json to no effect. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode. Can anyone tell me how to change the default color theme?

Comment: use `Ctrl+K Ctrl+T`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl+K Ctrl+T` command, if it doesn't work, go to the settings icon below in the left you'll find it there (color theme)

Comment: I tried this and it did nothing. I am on a Mac, so I tried vartions of this using the command key instead of control. Those also didn't work.